# Creating a simple login form

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple HTML log-in that is placed in a box. I want to have something like this:

[image]

I have tried a few things but they all seem to have been in vain. Here is my code thus far. HTML:

```
<div id="login_form">
    <form name="f1" method="post" action="login.php" id="f1">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="f1_label">User Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="username" value="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="f1_label">Password  :</td><td><input type="password" name="password" value=""  />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In" style="font-size:18px; " />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#login_form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 30%;
    right: 30%;
    bottom: 20%;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#f1 {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.f1_label {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I want the login box to be in the center of my browser, so I have made use of `#login_form`. I have a few questions: is the use of the `fieldset` tag a better way? When I used the `fieldset` tag, it created more issues; the appearance of the form and the size of the text & password fields changed.

I understand that `<table>` should be used for tabular data only, but the use of 
label in any other way seems to mess the size/width of password and username fields (it also requires more styling).

Is it poor coding practice to use `<table>` in a form? Will future browsers render the pages wrongly if I use `<table>`? Is keeping the `name` and `id` of the form the same a bad idea? I feel like keeping them the same does not create any issues (even with the use of jQuery in the same page).

Comment: Edit added information regarding f1_label class

Answer (score 7):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>Login Page</title>
      <style>
         /* Basics */
         html, body {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
         color: #444;
         -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
         background: #f0f0f0;
         }
         #container {
         position: fixed;
         width: 340px;
         height: 280px;
         top: 50%;
         left: 50%;
         margin-top: -140px;
         margin-left: -170px;
         background: #fff;
         border-radius: 3px;
         border: 1px solid #ccc;
         box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
         }
         form {
         margin: 0 auto;
         margin-top: 20px;
         }
         label {
         color: #555;
         display: inline-block;
         margin-left: 18px;
         padding-top: 10px;
         font-size: 14px;
         }
         p a {
         font-size: 11px;
         color: #aaa;
         float: right;
         margin-top: -13px;
         margin-right: 20px;
         -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
         -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
         transition: all .4s ease;
         }
         p a:hover {
         color: #555;
         }
         input {
         font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
         font-size: 12px;
         outline: none;
         }
         input[type=text],
         input[type=password] ,input[type=time]{
         color: #777;
         padding-left: 10px;
         margin: 10px;
         margin-top: 12px;
         margin-left: 18px;
         width: 290px;
         height: 35px;
         border: 1px solid #c7d0d2;
         border-radius: 2px;
         box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .4), 0 0 0 5px #f5f7f8;
         -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
         -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
         transition: all .4s ease;
         }
         input[type=text]:hover,
         input[type=password]:hover,input[type=time]:hover {
         border: 1px solid #b6bfc0;
         box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .7), 0 0 0 5px #f5f7f8;
         }
         input[type=text]:focus,
         input[type=password]:focus,input[type=time]:focus {
         border: 1px solid #a8c9e4;
         box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .4), 0 0 0 5px #e6f2f9;
         }
         #lower {
         background: #ecf2f5;
         width: 100%;
         height: 69px;
         margin-top: 20px;
         box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #fff;
         border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
         border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
         border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
         }
         input[type=checkbox] {
         margin-left: 20px;
         margin-top: 30px;
         }
         .check {
         margin-left: 3px;
         font-size: 11px;
         color: #444;
         text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
         }
         input[type=submit] {
         float: right;
         margin-right: 20px;
         margin-top: 20px;
         width: 80px;
         height: 30px;
         font-size: 14px;
         font-weight: bold;
         color: #fff;
         background-color: #acd6ef; /*IE fallback*/
         background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#acd6ef), to(#6ec2e8));
         background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #acd6ef 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
         background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #acd6ef 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
         border-radius: 30px;
         border: 1px solid #66add6;
         box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
         cursor: pointer;
         }
         input[type=submit]:hover {
         background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b6e2ff), to(#6ec2e8));
         background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #b6e2ff 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
         background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #b6e2ff 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
         }
         input[type=submit]:active {
         background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6ec2e8), to(#b6e2ff));
         background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #6ec2e8 0%, #b6e2ff 100%);
         background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #6ec2e8 0%, #b6e2ff 100%);
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- Begin Page Content -->
      <div id="container">
         <form action="login_process.php" method="post">
            <label for="loginmsg" style="color:hsla(0,100%,50%,0.5); font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;"><?php  echo @$_GET['msg'];?></label>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            <div id="lower">
               <input type="checkbox"><label class="check" for="checkbox">Keep me logged in</label>
               <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </div>
            <!--/ lower-->
         </form>
      </div>
      <!--/ container-->
      <!-- End Page Content -->
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi You seem to have misunderstood my question I just want html code that I can use to get the above layout mentioned in the picture.You have used mysql function it has been deprecated you should use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 4):

Great Start to learning login forms. You are right, fieldset may not be the best tag.

However, I highly suggest you code it in HTML5 by using its robust form features.

HTML5 is actually easier to learn than older HTML for creating forms.

For example, read the following.

```
<section class="loginform cf">  
    <form name="login" action="index_submit" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">  
        <ul>  
            <li><label for="usermail">Email</label>  
            <input type="email" name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required></li>  
            <li><label for="password">Password</label>  
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required></li>  
            <li>  
            <input type="submit" value="Login"></li>  
        </ul>  
    </form>  
</section>
```

Wasn't that easy for you to understand?

Try this http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-loginpage/ and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi,it looks easy let me try your code in jsfiddle have a slow connection :(

Comment: Download the source code http://demo.hongkiat.com/html5-loginpage/source.zip and try it with css and normalize file.

Answer (score 1):

**Check it -** 
You can try this code for your login form design as you ask thank you.

Explain css -

First, we define property font style and width And after that I have defined form id to set background image and the border And after that I have to define the header text in tag and after that I have added new  and define by.New to set background properties and width. Thanks

**Create a file `index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="login_form">
         <div class="new"><span>enter login details</span></div>
         <!-- This is your header text-->
         <form name="f1" method="post" action="login.php" id="f1">
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <td class="f1_label">User Name :</td>
                  <!-- This is your first Input Box Label-->
                  <td>
                     <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><!-- This is your first Input Box-->
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td class="f1_label">Password  :</td>
                  <!-- This is your Second Input Box Label-->
                  <td>
                     <input type="password" name="password" value=""  /><!-- This is your Second Input Box -->
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In" style="font-size:18px; " /><!-- This is your submit button -->
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </form>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Create css file `style.css`**

```
body {
    font-style: italic;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#login_form {}

#f1 {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 23px 1px 20px 114px;
}

.f1_label {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

span {
    color: white;
}

.new {
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You should add explanation to your answer.

Comment: This was flagged as low quality. Please try to explain the CSS code for the newbies. This answer might be deleted by the community soon.

Comment: Sir, Can you please suggest me, that where i can describe CSS in the code  like comment or out of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Using <table> is not a bad choice. Of course it is bit old fashioned.
```

But still not obsolete. But if you prefer you can use "Boostrap". 
There you have options for panels and enhanced forms.

**This is the sample code for your requirement. Used minimal styles to simplify.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Simple Login Form</title>
   </head>
   <style>
      table{
      border-style: solid;
      position: absolute;
      top: 40%;
      left : 40%;
      padding:10px;
      }
   </style>
   <body>
      <form method="post" action="login.php">
         <table>
            <tr bgcolor="black">
               <th colspan="3"><font color="white">Enter login details</th>
            </tr>
            <tr height="20"></tr>
            <tr>
               <td>User Name</td>
               <td>:</td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="username"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Password</td>
               <td>:</td>
               <td>
                  <input type="password" name="password"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10"></tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

edited @Asraful Haque answer with a bit of js to show and hide the box

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Login Page</title>
<style>
    /* Basics */
    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #444;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        background: #f0f0f0;
    }
    #container {
        position: fixed;
        width: 340px;
        height: 280px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -140px;
        margin-left: -170px;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        display: none;
    }
    form {
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    label {
        color: #555;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 18px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    p a {
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #aaa;
        float: right;
        margin-top: -13px;
        margin-right: 20px;
     -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
        transition: all .4s ease;
    }
    p a:hover {
        color: #555;
    }
    input {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        outline: none;
    }
    input[type=text],
    input[type=password] ,input[type=time]{
        color: #777;
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        margin-top: 12px;
        margin-left: 18px;
        width: 290px;
        height: 35px;
        border: 1px solid #c7d0d2;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .4), 0 0 0 5px #f5f7f8;
        -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
        transition: all .4s ease;
        }
    input[type=text]:hover,
    input[type=password]:hover,input[type=time]:hover {
        border: 1px solid #b6bfc0;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .7), 0 0 0 5px #f5f7f8;
    }
    input[type=text]:focus,
    input[type=password]:focus,input[type=time]:focus {
        border: 1px solid #a8c9e4;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .4), 0 0 0 5px #e6f2f9;
    }
    #lower {
        background: #ecf2f5;
        width: 100%;
        height: 69px;
        margin-top: 20px;
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #fff;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .check {
        margin-left: 3px;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #444;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    }
    input[type=submit] {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 80px;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #acd6ef; /*IE fallback*/
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#acd6ef), to(#6ec2e8));
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #acd6ef 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #acd6ef 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
        border-radius: 30px;
        border: 1px solid #66add6;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    input[type=submit]:hover {
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b6e2ff), to(#6ec2e8));
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #b6e2ff 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #b6e2ff 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
    }
    input[type=submit]:active {
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6ec2e8), to(#b6e2ff));
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #6ec2e8 0%, #b6e2ff 100%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #6ec2e8 0%, #b6e2ff 100%);
    }
</style>
<script>
    function clicker () {
        var login = document.getElementById("container");
        login.style.display="block";
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" id="link" onClick="clicker();">login</a>
    <!-- Begin Page Content -->
    <div id="container">
        <form action="login_process.php" method="post">
            <label for="loginmsg" style="color:hsla(0,100%,50%,0.5); font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;"><?php  echo @$_GET['msg'];?></label>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            <div id="lower">
                <input type="checkbox"><label class="check" for="checkbox">Keep me logged in</label>
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </div><!--/ lower-->
        </form>
    </div><!--/ container-->
    <!-- End Page Content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Best Login Page design in html and css</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: #f4f4f4;
color: #5a5656;
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.5em;
}
a { text-decoration: none; }
h1 { font-size: 1em; }
h1, p {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
strong {
font-weight: bold;
}
.uppercase { text-transform: uppercase; }

/* ---------- LOGIN ---------- */
#login {
margin: 50px auto;
width: 300px;
}
form fieldset input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
background-color: #e5e5e5;
border: none;
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
color: #5a5656;
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height: 50px;
outline: none;
padding: 0px 10px;
width: 280px;
-webkit-appearance:none;
}
form fieldset input[type="submit"] {
background-color: #008dde;
border: none;
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
color: #f4f4f4;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
height: 50px;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 300px;
-webkit-appearance:none;
}
form fieldset a {
color: #5a5656;
font-size: 10px;
}
form fieldset a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
.btn-round {
background-color: #5a5656;
border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
color: #f4f4f4;
display: block;
font-size: 12px;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
margin: 30px 125px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 50px;
}
.facebook-before {
background-color: #0064ab;
border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
color: #f4f4f4;
display: block;
float: left;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
width: 50px;
}
.facebook {
background-color: #0079ce;
border: none;
border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
color: #f4f4f4;
cursor: pointer;
height: 50px;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 250px;
}
.twitter-before {
background-color: #189bcb;
border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
color: #f4f4f4;
display: block;
float: left;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
width: 50px;
}
.twitter {
background-color: #1bb2e9;
border: none;
border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
color: #f4f4f4;
cursor: pointer;
height: 50px;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 250px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="login">
<h1><strong>Welcome.</strong> Please login.</h1>
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="get">
<fieldset>
<p><input type="text" required value="Username" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Username'" onFocus="if(this.value=='Username')this.value='' "></p>
<p><input type="password" required value="Password" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Password'" onFocus="if(this.value=='Password')this.value='' "></p>
<p><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
</fieldset>
</form>
<p><span class="btn-round">or</span></p>
<p>
<a class="facebook-before"></a>
<button class="facebook">Login Using Facbook</button>
</p>
<p>
<a class="twitter-before"></a>
<button class="twitter">Login Using Twitter</button>
</p>
</div> <!-- end login -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Your answer puts the form in a different way than the OP has mentioned.

Comment: You should give the credit to the author for his works by mentioning source link in the answer. Source for above post [www.aspdotnet-suresh.com](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/06/best-login-page-design-in-html-css-with.html)